# sending , retrieving data from designer of pages using query string of URL

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a iframe in aspx page whose src property is set to html page url along with data is sent syntax is as follows :

```
<iframe src="testing.htm?info1='Hello'"></iframe>
```

and on html page in onload of Body tag i have called a function that will read from the query string and assign data to a text box. Code is as follows:

```
var info;
  function _Form_Loader() {
        try {
            debugger;
            Info = request.QueryString('info1');  // input is the textbox.

            var Txt = $("#Input1");
            Txt.Text = Info ;
        } catch (e) {

        } 
    }
```

What is wrong here i suppose query string is the problem .
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are assiging src to that textbox but where u are assigining for that

I think u need to pass Txt.Text = Info; or just try  `$("#Input1").val(Info);`

Try this ...